# Solving for c in Probability Density Fucntion

Tags: probability, variance, density-function

Let X be a random variable with a probability density function (PDF) given by

```
f(x) = cx^2, if |x|<= 1

          0, otherwise
```

⦁   Solve for c.

⦁   Calculate  E(X)

⦁   Calculate Var(X)

How do we solve this question?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this? For instance, have you checked how $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ are defined for continuous random variables?

Comment: **Basic plan.** Sketch out the function $cx^2$, for the domain $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.  The area under that curve (in between those constraints) must be equal to $1$, for this to be a PDF.  For what value of $c$ is that area equal to $1$?  Then calculate $\int_{x=-1}^1 xf(x) \, dx$ to obtain $E(X)$, and $\int_{x=-1}^1 x^2f(x) \, dx$ to obtain $E(X^2)$; use $\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$.

Comment: I went about solving for c by taking the ∫ from 0 to 1 of cx^2 and setting it equal to 1. My answer is c=3. Im not sure if it's correct because im not sure what the absolute value of x is implying.

Comment: Ahh I see @Brian Tung. So we must take the integral from -1 to 1 because of the absolute value of x! So this would mean c = 3/2!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definitions:
$$\begin{align}1~=~&\int_{\lvert x\rvert\leqslant 1} cx^2\operatorname d x & =~& \tfrac 13 cx^3\Big\rvert_{x=-1}^{x=~1}\\[2ex] \mathsf E(X)~=~& \int_{\lvert x\rvert\leqslant 1} x\cdot cx^2\operatorname d x  \\[2ex] \mathsf {Var}(X)~=~& \int_{\lvert x\rvert\leqslant 1} x^2\cdot cx^2\operatorname d x~-~\mathsf E(X)^2 
\end{align}$$